# how this function do in the stack, calldata, and memory

Tags: solidity, assembly

I am not familiar with the inline assembly. May I ask what happened in the arrLength method and how it operates in stack, memory, and calldata

```
pragma solidity 0.4.5;
contract Test {

    // for example: arr = [ 3, 3 ]
    // msg.data =  
    // 4 bytes Selector                                                   
    // 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020 
    // 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002 
    // 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
    // 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003 
    function arrLength(uint[] arr) constant external returns (uint len) {
        assembly {
            // two items will be added to the stack rather, position and length:
            arr =: len pop
        }
    }
}
```